# How can i import contact numbers from a pdf or excel file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, excel, android-studio, pdf

I am making a directory app in which i have to display phone numbers of different sectors of the state. I have a pdf file containing 2000 contacts with their emails, phone numbers and address and have to load these contacts into my android app. I am totally new to this, i searched internet but could not get where to start.Most of the examples show how to display contacts already stored in the phone but in this i have to pull a static list myself to the app.
Please guide how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add [pdfbox.jar](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) to your project:

```
        File file = new File(fileName);   
        FileInputStream in = null;   
        try {   
            in = new FileInputStream(fileName);   
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(in);   
            parser.parse();   
            PDDocument pdfdocument = parser.getPDDocument();   
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();   
            String result = stripper.getText(pdfdocument);   
            System.out.println(result);   

        } catch (Exception e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } finally {   
            if (in != null) {   
                try {   
                    in.close();   
                } catch (IOException e1) {   
                }   
            }   
        }
```

the **result** is all the pdf text contained.

Comment: how to call filename here from assets folder?

Comment: `InputStream in = getAssets().open("aaa.txt");PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(in); `  If this doesn't work,you have to copy the file into external  storage.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a propetary standard and is not easy to read(sometimes impossible).

If you are starting now i would strong recomend you to copy all your data in a plain text file and use standard java class to read it.

If you can't even copy the data from pdf in a new file text file using your computer, you will need to use an OCR program to do the task and the programming path to achieve this will get way more dificult.

Comment: what if i get the data in excel ? Could you please provide the code for all this?